# Some items are missing when using since parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

I'm facebook graph API user.
Recently found that `since` parameter works weird.
I'm using that to find all upcoming events and filter out past events for a particular venue.

For instance:
When I use query like this

```
/v2.5/481931581856759/events?access_token=&limit=5
```

I getting all events.
But if I add `since` variable, some events are missing

```
/v2.5/481931581856759/events?access_token=&limit=5&since=1471468270
```

In this case can not find an event with start_time "2016-10-28T19:00:00-0700".

Why that happens or I misunderstand something?